# HashMap cannot be cast to model when trying to iterate set

Tags: java, iterator, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa for creating micro services. In repository I am using  `JPQL` query. Using following code I am able to get set of data. But I want to iterate set of data for further logic.

For iteration I used `for each` but when I am using for each loop I am getting error `"java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.spacestudy.model.RoomDepartmentMapping",`

```
public Set<RoomDepartmentMapping> loadStatusOfRooms() {

        Set<RoomDepartmentMapping> roomDeptMapping = roomDeptMappingRepo.findStaus();           

        return roomDeptMapping;     
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface RoomDepartmentMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<RoomDepartmentMapping, Integer> {

     @Query("select new map(roomDeptMap.sStatus as sStatus) from RoomDepartmentMapping as roomDeptMap")
        Set<RoomDepartmentMapping> findStaus();
}
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "sStatus": "A"
  },
  {
    "sStatus": "I"
  },
  {
    "sStatus": "R"
  }
]
```

**Expecting Result**

```
[
  {
    "sStatus": "Accepted"
  },
  {
    "sStatus": "In Progress"
  },
  {
    "sStatus": "Remaining"
  }
]
```

For getting above expected result I am trying to iterate Set of data using for each and planning to use switch case. But I am not able to iterate using following loop.

**For each loop**

```
for(RoomDepartmentMapping roomDeptMappingObj:roomDeptMapping) {

        System.out.println(roomDeptMappingObj);
    }
```

Can any one tell me why I am not able to iterate set using for each loop?
Or please suggest any another way to do that.

Comment: During the runtime hibernate is actually giving you set of `HashMap` when calling `roomDeptMapping` method. You probably need to update your  JPA query.

Comment: @tsolakp you should write answer as answer instead of comments.

Comment: @Jens Schauder. You are probably right, but sometimes just showing the cause without a solution might not be good enough for an answer.

Comment: @ tsolakp I want result in key,value format so I am using map there. Can you tell what I need to change in query

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name of your method I will assume that you need all available status values.
The query will be:

```
 @Query("select distinct rdm.sStatus from RoomDepartmentMapping rdm")
 Set<String> findStatus();
```

- distinct => you need set
- Set => RoomDepartmentMapping sStatus is a String

Comment: I want result in key, value format, If I am using String I am only getting value as string not key